# runtime error SIGSEGV in c code on spoj for PALIN

Tags: c, palindrome

A positive integer is called a palindrome if its representation in the decimal system is the same when read from left to right and from right to left. For a given positive integer K of not more than 1000000 digits, write the value of the smallest palindrome larger than K to output. Numbers are always displayed without leading zeros.
first i tried to save all the palindromes and then check for printing the number.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int array[2000],index=0;
long long n;

void savepalindrome()
{
    long long lim=1000000;
    long long i=1;

    for(i=1;i<lim;i++)
    {
        if(checkpalindrome(i)==1) {
            array[index]=i; index++;
        }
    }
}

int  checkpalindrome(long long i) {
    long long reverse=0, rem,temp;
    temp=i;
    while(temp!=0)
    {
        rem=temp%10;
        reverse=reverse*10+rem;
        temp/=10;
    }
    if(reverse==i) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

int main() {
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    savepalindrome();
    while(t--) {
        scanf("%d",&n);
        index=0;
        while(array[index]<=n) {
            index++;
        }

        if(index<=1998) printf("%d\n",array[index]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your exact question

Comment: @MohitJain i have to find the next palindrome for a given number . it's working fine on ideone http://ideone.com/W9p1xZ but not on spoj . showing runtime error.

Comment: `For a given positive integer K of not more than 1000000 digits`. Have you tested for a 100 digit number? You'll see same [sigsegv](http://ideone.com/qdwggx) on ideone also.

Comment: yes, @MohitJain  on my system it's giving the correct output and on ideone as well

Comment: no need its global array. by default it is initialized to zero

Comment: @nikhilmehta , Yeah. Forgot about that!

Comment: @sarvajeetsuman Check [this ideone link](http://ideone.com/qdwggx)(shared in above comment also), if I make the input number very large, I get Runtime error

Answer (score 0):

though if long long int is not capable of storing 1000000 digit number it will overflow in long long int's range.i think your index is going out of array bound.it seems only reason for SIGSEGV. SIGSEGV is sent to a process only if it accesses a memory location that is not valid.

Comment: debug your program and see to what value your index is going to